# How to access function inside attr directive from parent? (Angular2)

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I would like to be able to access the functions inside my attr directive through user interaction in the parent. I have prepared a plunk to demonstrate;

https://plnkr.co/edit/MZONsuh7O6bWgZfE0mZ2?p=preview

In this example, an event is fired when a user types into the input. I am wondering if it is possible once this happens, to also fire off the `onChange()` function inside the attr directive?

Not sure how this can be achieved, any advice is welcome!

Thanks,

Code below

---

app.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <div testGenerator></div>
      <input type="text" (input)="detectChange($event)" />
  `,
})
export class App {

  constructor() {
  }

  detectChange(e){
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

}
```

test directive:

```
import {Directive} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[testGenerator]'
})
export class TestDirective {

  constructor() {
  }

  onChange(){
    console.log("hello")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way is to use directive `exportAs` option and template reference. See [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2INptXnWQGFNEObKbi4h?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`ViewChild`** **`API`** to call directive's function from parent component as shown below,

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/zDVtxuzNPssxzBlpozjv?p=preview**

```
export class App {
  @ViewChild(TestDirective) vc:TestDirective;  //<<<---added

  constructor() {
  }

  detectChange(e){
    console.log(e.target.value)
    this.vc.onChange();                        //<<<---added
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Template-driven solution is also possible. Bind `inputValue` to `Directive`:
[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/oiKWPgP5FnhUDRTfU9X6)